# JSON.parse: unexpected character when fetching data from NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to fetch the data from my localhost Node server but I still getting this "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". It works fine when I fetch from https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10, but not for my own JSON array.

**server.js** (backend)

```
//RENDER HTML PAGE TO GET THE RESULTS
app.get('/device', isLoggedIn, function(req,res)
{
    fs.readFile('./public/list.html', 'utf8', (err, data)=> {
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
});

//GENERATE MY JSON ARRAY
app.get('/mydevices', isLoggedIn, function(req,res)
{
    connection.query("\
        SELECT `dispositivos`.`nome` \
        FROM `dispositivos` JOIN `usuarios` \
        ON `usuarios`.`id` = `dispositivos`.`user_id` AND `user_id`='" + req.user.id + "'", (err,result)=>
    {
        res.json({'results': result});
        // console.log(result)
    });
});
```

**controller.js** (frontend - NOT working for my JSON)

```
window.onload = function(){
  function createNode(element) {
      return document.createElement(element);
  }

  function append(parent, el) {
    return parent.appendChild(el);
  }

  const ul = document.getElementById('mydevices');
  const url = 'http://localhost:777/mydevices';
  fetch(url)
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data) {
    let devices = data.results;
    return devices.map(function(device) {
      let li = createNode('li'),
          // img = createNode('img'),
          span = createNode('span');
      // img.src = device.picture.medium;
      span.innerHTML = `${device.nome}`;
      // append(li, img);
      append(li, span);
      append(ul, li);
    })
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });   
};
```

**controller.js** (frontend - WORKING for randomuser.me API)

```
window.onload = function(){
  function createNode(element) {
      return document.createElement(element);
  }

  function append(parent, el) {
    return parent.appendChild(el);
  }

  const ul = document.getElementById('authors');
  const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10';
  fetch(url)
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data) {
    let authors = data.results;
    return authors.map(function(author) {
      let li = createNode('li'),
          img = createNode('img'),
          span = createNode('span');
      img.src = author.picture.medium;
      span.innerHTML = `${author.name.first} ${author.name.last}`;
      append(li, img);
      append(li, span);
      append(ul, li);
    })
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });   
};
```

In the rendered html I have id="devices" (of course I change it to "authors" when I want to use randomuser API).

Comment: I'm guessing that you're not making this request in a page served from `http://localhost:777`, right?

Comment: Go to the Network tab of DevTools and look at the raw response.

Answer (score 0):

"unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" always means the result isn't JSON, and *almost* always means (in the web context) that you're getting an error page instead.

Two issues:

1. (The main issue.) You're trying to make a cross-origin request (to `http://localhost:777`, but from some other origin, I'm guessing `http://localhost:80` or similar), but not issuing the necessary [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) headers to enable the call from the origin you're making the call from. In contrast, `https://randomuser.me` enables requests from all origins.
2. (Not the main issue.) You're not checking that the request succeeded. This is (in my view) a failure of the `fetch` API, it has a major footgun in this regard I see fired here on SO almost every day. (Details in [my blog post on it](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).). Add:

   ```
   .then(resp => {
       if (!resp.ok) {
           throw new Error(resp.status);
       }
   })
   ```

   ...before your `.then(resp => resp.json())`.